# Length of uploaded file in Ruby on Rails decreases after UploadedFile.read

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

On a RoR app that i've inherited, a test is failing that involves a file upload.  The assertion that fails looks like so:

```
assert_equal File.size("#{RAILS_ROOT}/test/fixtures/#{filename}"), @candidate.picture.length
```

It fails with (the test file is 69 bytes):

```
<69> expected but was <5>.
```

This is after a post using:

```
fixture_file_upload(filename, content_type, :binary)
```

In the candidate model, the uploaded file is assigned to a property that is then saved to a mediumblob in MySQL.  It looks to me like the uploaded file is 69 bytes, but after it is assigned to the model property (using UploadedFile.read), the length is showing as only 5 bytes.

So this code:

```
puts "file.length=" + file.length.to_s
self.picture = file.read
puts "self.picture.length=" + self.picture.length.to_s
```

results in this output:

```
file.length=69
self.picture.length=5
```

I'm at a bit of a loss as to why this is, any ideas?

Comment: Is the data _actually_ wrong or is the file length just not what you expected?

Comment: This comment was helpful, since looking at the data that ended up in the db showed that is was corrupt and not a proper image.  See answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This came down to a Windows/Ruby idiosyncrasy, where reading the file appeared to be happening in text mode.  There is an extension in this app in test_helper, something like:

```
class ActionController::TestUploadedFile
  # Akward but neccessary for testing since an ActionController::UploadedFile subtype is expected
  include ActionController::UploadedFile

  def read
    tempfile = File.new(self.path)
    tempfile.read
  end
end
```

And apparently, on Windows, there is a specific IO method that can be called to force the file into binary mode.  Calling this method on the tempfile, like so:

```
tempfile.binmode
```

caused everything to work as expected, with the read from the UploadedFile matching the size of the fixture file on disk.